# How to request access token and make Http call in HttpPost action method?

Tags: azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-mvc, access-token, azure-ad-msal

I am trying to access a protected resource using Azure AD access token in my ASP.NET Core MVC web application. I was able to get access token and make successful Http call with the following code.

Program.cs

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

var initialScopes = 
builder.Configuration["DownstreamApi:Scopes"]?.Split(' ') ?? 
builder.Configuration["MicrosoftGraph:Scopes"]?.Split(' ');





builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"))
            .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(initialScopes)
                .AddDownstreamApi("DownstreamApi",builder.Configuration.GetSection("DownstreamApi"))
                .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
    
    builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
    {
        var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
            .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
            .Build();
        options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
    });
    builder.Services.AddRazorPages()
        .AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();

var app = builder.Build();

if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
   
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
app.MapRazorPages();

app.Run();
```

My controller:

```
[Authorize]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;

    readonly IAuthorizationHeaderProvider _authorizationHeaderProvider;
    public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger, IAuthorizationHeaderProvider authorizationHeaderProvider)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _authorizationHeaderProvider = authorizationHeaderProvider;
    }

    [AuthorizeForScopes(Scopes = new[] { "api://{my_app_id}/access_as_user"})]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        // Acquire the access token.
        string[] scopes = new string[] { "api://{my_app_id}/access_as_user" };
        string accessToken = await _authorizationHeaderProvider.CreateAuthorizationHeaderForUserAsync(scopes);

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", accessToken);

        string json = await client.GetStringAsync({resource_url});

        return View(json);
    }
    
    ...
    }
```

Now I want to receive a parameter value from view and get corresponding data from the protected resource. I tried the following code:

```
[Authorize]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;

readonly IAuthorizationHeaderProvider _authorizationHeaderProvider;

public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger, IAuthorizationHeaderProvider authorizationHeaderProvider)
{
    _logger = logger;
    _authorizationHeaderProvider = authorizationHeaderProvider;
}

[AuthorizeForScopes(Scopes = new[] { "api://{my_app_id}/access_as_user" })]
public IActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpGet]
[AuthorizeForScopes(Scopes = new[] { "api://{my_app_id}/access_as_user" })]
public async Task<string> GetToken()
{
    //Acquire the access token
    string[] scopes = new string[] { "api://{my_app_id}/access_as_user" };
    string token = await _authorizationHeaderProvider.CreateAuthorizationHeaderForUserAsync(scopes); 
    return token;
}

[HttpPost]
[AuthorizeForScopes(Scopes = new[] { "api://{my_app_id}/access_as_user" })]
public IActionResult Index(string id)
{
    string accessToken = GetToken().Result;
    
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", accessToken);
    resource_url = $"https://....../{id}"

    string json = await client.GetStringAsync({resource_url});

    return View(json);
}
 ....
}
```

When I run the code and input the "id" in the browser, I had to input twice. First time no response, after inputting second time I got the following error.

> HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success:
> 403 (Forbidden).

Comment: Hi @Ibrahim Memet, the 403 authenticated users with insufficient permissions. How do you configure the custom Authorize attribute([AuthorizeForScopes])? Could you pls also share the Program.cs or Startup.cs?

Comment: Hi @Rena  I updated my question adding program.cs. I added custom authentication scheme in my Azure AD portal, then added a section in appsettings.json with the custom authentication scheme, which is "api://{my_app_id}/access_as_user".

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that Microsoft Edge was causing this issue. When run the code with chrome, it worked without problem. Then I changed the "supported account type" from multitenant to single tenant in Azure AD app registration, following this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-modify-supported-accounts). Then I was able to run the code in Microsoft Edge as well.